# Matlab arctanh function

Tags: matlab, math

I keep receiving an error while using the `arctanh` function on Matlab

Undefined function `arctanh` for input arguments of type 'double'.

I am doing this calculation

```
A = mu*arctanh(l2./(R2+R3))
```

Where `l2` and `R2` are vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arctanh` is only in MuPAD Notebook Interface:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/arctanh.html

Normally within MATLAB you should use `atanh`:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atanh.html